# Jquery plugins giving errors $(...).ionRangeSlider not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use jquery plugins in my react application. Every time I try to use some jquery third party plugin, I get an error saying $(...).somePlugin not a function. Currently I am trying to use ionRangeSlider. It is giving me error

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).ionRangeSlider is not a function
```

js file

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'bootstrap-tagsinput'

class AddTagSection extends Component {


    componentDidMount=()=> {

        this.slider = $(this.inputSlider).ionRangeSlider();

    }

<div className="irs-wrapper">
                            <input type="text"  ref={node=>this.inputSlider=node} className='input-slider' id="ionSlider-newTag" name="ionSlider"/>
                        </div>
```

Below is the function which is getting called in ionRangeSlider.js (plugin)

```
$.fn.ionRangeSlider = function (options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!$.data(this, "ionRangeSlider")) {
                $.data(this, "ionRangeSlider", new IonRangeSlider(this, options, plugin_count++));
            }
        });
    };
```

As far as I have read on web, this is a multiple jquery clashes issue.

About my Application: My project has jquery installed via npm. So there is one jquery present in package.json. I have also included jquery in scripts in my index.jade file. So there is another one there.

This is not an issue of jquery placed after plugin's js file. I placed jquery at the top in the scripts of index.jade file.

```
block head_scripts

         script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js') 
    script(src='/public/ion.rangeSlider.js')
    link(href='/public/normalize.css' rel="stylesheet")
    link(href='/public/ion.rangeSlider.css' rel="stylesheet")
    link(href='/public/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css' rel='stylesheet')
```

I also tried noConfilct. But that too didn't work.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$( ".slider" ).ionRangeSlider();
```

I tried including jquery in my webpack config.js file

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            React: 'react',
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        }),
```

Nothing from the above worked. Everytime I got the same error.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like you've only included the IonRangeSlider CSS files, not the JS

Comment: No I have included it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan anything else ypu think I am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If your project contains a different version of `jQuery` than the one specified in `ionRangeSlider` `package.json` dependencies and you're using `yarn` to install your project's dependencies and `webpack` to bundle the project, then this might be the source of the problem. `Yarn` will install `node_modules` even in `ion-range-slider` folder, which will cause that the `webpack` will build the project with your `jQuery`, as well as with the one in `ion-range-slider/node_modules`. Hence the jQuery versions clash. `ionRangeSlider` initiates with the first `jQuery` and your project's `jQuery` won't contain it.

It's kind of a fault of `ionRangeSlider` developer because he should not specify the `jQuery` in `dependencies`, but instead in `peerDependencies`.

Comment: This should be fixed in the latest release: https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/issues/546#issuecomment-567851060

Answer (score 0):

try changing internal url to external url  for rangeslider

```html
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" />
```

then do import Slider from 'react-rangeslider' if not using the es6 transpiler then do var Slider = require('react-rangeslider')

Comment: External url is not available for ionRangeSlider.

Comment: But why do i need to do that. I am already including script. I haven't installed it via npm as i have included in scripts.

Comment: i have edited my snippet .now u can try with external url. some day I am going through issue like this  then i use external url it works well may be you can try and see

Comment: try using this version of jquery   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: No luck. Same error with this too. I think it is multiple jquery clash issue as i have mentioned in ques.

Comment: are you using more the one jquery script ? or only one which you are showing on index.jade file ? if not then try doing this   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../static/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146572/discussion-between-apurvg-and-malik-kamran-abid).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error, looks like a Jquery version conflict please try downgrading ion-rangeslider in package.json "ion-rangeslider": "2.2.0".